# Well kicks off after just one cycle

Tags: pump, well

My well will pressure up to 50lbs and turn off when not in use. When I turn on a water line it will cycle once or maybe twice in between 30-50 like it's supposed to. At some point after it moves past the 30lbs spot on the gauge and supposed to click back on. It empties the pressure tank, and the pump does not turn back on until I trip the reset on pressure gauge. Then it will do it all over again.

Its a 4" submersible 1.5 hp with a 100 bladdered pressure tank. The pump is 4 joints (80feet) down into a well that has about 200 feet of water. The pump hits water at 20 feet.

I just replaced the pump today and the pressure switch and gauge. After the short cycle, I returned the switch and gauge and It continued to have the same problem. The pressure tank has 27 lbs of pressure on it when no water is in it.

Kind of has me baffled. Any help?

Comment: What are you using for a pressure switch?

Comment: A common water source 30-50 pressure switch/interruptor.

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar problem with a square D pressure switch locking out in my case it was the position the switch was in.

These have a safety that you are resetting so if the actual pressure is below the set point (low water level pump running but not building pressure) it requires a manual reset my pressure was set 50 and the air in the bladder was charged to 48 and the switch was still tripping,

I rotated the switch tightened it and brought the lever on side and it became intermittent another 90 so the flag was on top and it has worked correctly since.

The switch was probably designed for verticals mount and I had mounted it horizontally, so this may be your problem also mr gravity was pulling the lever to the safety point , I had tossed the instructions but this may be the problem, it sounds similar to what I had, the tank pressure should be a few psi below the cut in set point.

Comment: I  actually did drop the pressure in my bladder to 25 to try to stop it, but to no avail. I returned the pressure switch, which was a lowlevel/30-50bs switch and just got a regular 30-50 switch and that seemed to have done the trick. I left the tank at 25lbs and according to the pressure switch, it clicks back on when its says 30lbs. Not sure how that works but its working. Gonna keep an eye on it for a while, dont need to leave it and have it have a fault and burn up a moter, those things at cheap!

Comment: With the pump turning on above your charge level you have a shorter “off” time, since you returned the lockout switch you won’t have any further problems I might bump the bladder pressure up a little I like 2 -3 psi below the cut in but 5 is not a problem.